# Erro ao tentar adicionar as Fields atualizadas no ClientDataSet

Tags: delphi-7, tclientdataset

Estou tentado atualizar as Fields dos meus ClientDataSet's com as variáveis novas do banco, porém me deparei com o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por qual motivo isso poderia estar ocorrendo?

Join do TSQLDataSet:

```
select E.*, S.Suprimento from Estoque E, Suprimento S 
  Where S.Codigo = E.CodigoSuprimento 
    and E.Usado = 0
   Order by S.Suprimento
```

Após editar as fields o seguinte erro Ocorre:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seu BD é postgresql?

Comment: Sim, a aplicação antes utilizava o Banco de Dados Firebird agora é PostgreSQL

Comment: Tudo indica que é um "where" ou "join" onde você compara um varchar com um inteiro. Pode ser também o tipo do parâmetro que você inseriu no componente. Verifique se há parâmetro, caso contrário altere remova o "where" para verificação, assim você verifica o real problema por eliminação

Comment: @Sorack Eu olhei o código e não encontrei um erro em algum "Where" ou "Join" vou editar a pergunta com o "Join" que esta no meu `TSQLDataSet`

Comment: Consegui acessar as Fields agora, o erro estava no `E.Usado = 0` que por ser uma String teria que estar `E.Usado = '0'`

Comment: Tenta alterar a linha "and E.Usado = 0" para "and E.Usado = '0'"

Comment: Justamente. Vou colocar essa resposta e agradeço se você me der um +1 ^^

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47765/discussion-between-sorack-and-r-santos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tudo indica que é um `where` ou `join` onde você compara um `varchar` com um `inteiro`. Pode ser também o tipo do parâmetro que você inseriu no componente. Verifique se há parâmetro, caso contrário altere remova o `where` para verificação, assim você verifica o real problema por eliminação. Baseado na sua `SQL` provavelmente o erro não irá mais ocorrer caso você utilize a seguinte:

```
select E.*,
       S.Suprimento
  from Estoque E,
       Suprimento S 
 Where S.Codigo = E.CodigoSuprimento
   and E.Usado = '0'
 Order by S.Suprimento desc;
```

Comment: Eu Editei minha pergunta para poder te mostrar o erro que começou a dar agora depois de editar as Fields, se puder me ajudar

Comment: Converti os comentários da pergunta em chat pra podermos tentar identificar o problema.